# Problems with contenteditable in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I am working on a Javascript WYSIWYG editor in Firefox.  I am using a div with the contenteditable attribute set to true in order to accomplish this (I cannot use a contenteditable iframe for this particular project).  This contenteditable div is nested in another div that is not contenteditable.  I am encountering the following two problems when using execCommand to apply formatting, including font style and size, as well as bold, italic, and underline:

- When all text in the div is selected, execCommand simply does not work.  execCommand works fine when only part of the text is selected, but does nothing when all of the text is selected.
- Applying formatting with no text selected yields unexpected results.  For example, when calling execCommand('bold') with no text selected and then typing results in bold text being typed until a spacebar is inserted, at which point the bold formatting is lost (until another space is inserted, interestingly enough; then the text becomes bold again).

To see what I mean, please try running the following HTML code in Firefox 3:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<button onClick="execCommand('bold', false, null);">Bold</button>
<div style="width: 300px; border: 1px solid #000000;">
<div contenteditable="true">Some editable text</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please try the following:

- Select the word "Some" only.  Click the Bold button.  This will make the text bold, as expected.
- Select the entire phrase "Some editable text" (either manually or using CTRL-A).  Click the Bold button.  Nothing happens.  This demonstrates the first bug shown above.
- Hit the backspace key to clear the div.  Click the Bold button and begin typing.  Type a few words with spaces.  This will demonstrate the second bug.

Any ideas on what could be causing these problems and how to work around them would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One thing that I forgot to note - the above problems are in Firefox only; Safari and IE don't seem to have these issues.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. In Firefox 3.6.3, I can't replicate the first problem: selecting all of the editable text and pressing the button toggles boldness as expected. However, the other two issues I do see. They'll be bugs in Mozilla's implementation of `contenteditable`.

Interestingly, the alternate-words-bold problem doesn't happen if you use `designMode` rather than `contenteditable`. I suspect it will solve your other problem too. This involves making the whole document editable, rather than just elements within it:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.designMode = "on";
};
```

If this isn't an option and you need the fine control that `contenteditable` provides, you'll need to implement your own version of the bold command using DOM manipulation and Ranges. This will be quite involved to get working in IE and non-IE browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I updated Firefox to 3.6.3 from 3.5.9, and the first issue is gone!  They must have found and corrected that bug.
Unfortunately, designmode isn't an option for me.  That would only work if the editable area is an iframe, but I am working with a div. Turning designmode on makes the entire document editable.  There must be another workaround, because Nicedit (http://nicedit.com/demos.php), which doesn't use an iframe, doesn't have the bold problem. I might just have to examine the Nicedit source code, unless someone else has any ideas on how to make this work...

Comment: Whoops!  I missed the last sentences regarding writing a custom bold command.  I might just do that; the only browser that is causing problems is FF, so my alternate solution would only have to be written to be compatible with FF.
Thanks again for your help!  It's much appreciated!

Comment: This is such a weird bug.  Anyway, after experimenting some more I was able to fix it by calling focus() on the contenteditable div prior to the execCommand call.  It now works without any problems.